# Simulator not working after using size classes to change constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, size-classes

I am learning how to adjust my app on multiple iPhone devices.

I have changed one of the button's layout constraints about margins. In IB, I can see it works fine. However, when I run the app in simulator, it's still not adjust to the size of the device.

- In Instance Builder, works fine:

[image: works fine in Instance Builder: w Any | h Any]

[image: works fine in Instance Builder: w Compact | h Regular]

- In simulator, not working as I expected:

[image: In simulator]

[image: In simulator]

PS: I am using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a). I created this app using iOS 8.0 SDK.

[image: my deploying setting]

Comment: What are the constraints of the label, do you have Horizontal Center in Container?

Comment: @gabbler Yes. A Horizontal Center-0, a Leading-20 and a Trailing-20 to margin

Comment: And also a Vertical Center. But that's not that important.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, the second and third image is not the same but both on iPhone 6.

Comment: @gabbler They are both on iPhone 6, but one in portrait, the other in landscape. I just got it -- it has to be cleaned first, then run again, so that it will work fine. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out -- you have to first CLEAN it, then RUN. It will work out fine.

To clean it, follow this pic:

[image: Product --> Clean]